# Inserir dados de um JSON em uma banco Sqlite com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, sqlite

Estou tentando inserir os dados que pego da minha API, no banco SQLITE do meu app, já pesquisei muito mas além de não conseguir fazer também não consegui entender como posso fazer isso.

Segue o código do meu `service`:

```
app.service('CategoriesService', function($http, $q) {

  var url = 'http://meusite.com.br/api/';

  return {
    allCategories: function() {
      return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        console.log(JSON);
        return response.data;
      });
    }
  }

})
```

Cheguei a usar o `stringify` para ver se ficava mais fácil de inserir, mas não consegui fazer com os exemplos que encontrei e muito menos com os testes que fiz.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, não sei se é a maneira correta de fazer isso, mas está funcionando.

```
app.service('CategoriesService', function($http, $q) {

  var url = 'http://meusite.com.br/api/';

  return {
    allCategories: function() {
      return $http.get(url + 'categories').then(function(response) {
        var result = response.data;

        result.forEach(function(category) {
          db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var query = "INSERT INTO tblCategories (id, category_name) VALUES (?,?)",
                params = [category.category_id, category.category_name];
            tx.executeSql(query, params);
            console.log('Salvo');
          }, function(error) {
            console.log('Erro');
          });
        })

        return response.data;
      });
    }
  }

})
```